# Как подружить nuxt(node) и php?

Tags: php, node.js, nuxt.js

Собственно есть сервер на нем настроен apache+php и отдельно крутится на nodejs nuxt, стал вопрос, как увязать их вместе.
NUXT отвечает за фронтэнд и php за бекэнд и работу с mysql.

Разгрузил порты NUXT на порт 80, и php отвечает на 8090.

Теперь стоит вопрос выполнить запрос к php чтобы залить на сервер файлы и получать данные с базы. Т.к. обращаюсь по линку /api естественно node не знает что такое php и не отрабатывает.

По структуре:

```
/var/www/html
/var/www/node
```

В данной ситуации пока пришел только в варианту выполнять кросс запрос, но тогда нужно давать права с html в ноду заливать фалы которые загружаются клиентом.

Буду рад выслушать любые варианты решения этой задачи. Вплоть до переписи бекэнда. Тогда вопрос что использовать для заливки фото, js to mysql есть плагин то не хочу передавать на сторону клиента запросы в коде.

Спасибо всем кто дочитал :)

Comment: Если Вы используете Nodejs только для того, чтобы отдавать html, то логично, запросы для бэка, отправлять прямо на бэк

Comment: Node используется для SSR на nuxt что увеличивает как скорость загрузки страниц так и исключает передачу лишнего.

Comment: Из Вашего комментария, не совсем понятно, что Вам мешает запрос сделать прямо на сервер php

Comment: Возможно плохо объяснил, если я обращаюсь как /api то такой папки нет, если ее создать то php в нем не работает. Приходится обращаться на порт 8090 и тогда это как крос запрос, он определяется браузером как на другой сайт. Вот ищу варианты, как обойтись без них, нашел статью с proxy под nuxt но пока головой не дошел. Ищу варианты.

Comment: А apache не может запросы к /api перенаправить на порт 8090?

Comment: по факту это же не apache ответит а nuxt, точнее один из вариантов сервера (express...) все зависит от установки. Я думал о редиректе, но не уверен что он корректно отработает при передаче данных, тем более там совмещен get+post типа ?show=data и в посте остальное